# "rails g controller welcome" not creating welcome_controller.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when i excuite the command "rails g controller welcome" in iTerm on macpro(10.12), there did not create the file of app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb , it just show me "identical  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb" ,just as the picture shows .
and here is my github https://github.com/xiaoyiam/job-listing

and here is the link of the picture http://xiaoyi-blog.logdown.com/posts/1749203

Comment: May need more details; it's a simple file comparison so there must be *some* reason it's indicating it's there.

Comment: Seems like the controller is already created there try to check if you are checking in the correct directory or try reloading the files in editor

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please include the error in the question itself, not as a remote picture.

Comment: you find it! i am a newer ,i am learning the guide about how to ask questions the right way , though i am not good at english ,i will keep learning .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on console:

```
$ spring stop                   # (If you're using spring)
$ rails d controller welcome
$ rails g controller welcome
```

Comment: The screenshot shows
`rails g controller welcome running Via Spring Preloader`

Comment: it worked !  the "welcome controller .welcome helper~" was already exited,so i do as you said ,delete them ,and then generate them again,it helped.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `welcome_controller` already exists and is a duplicate.

Try working on that same controller or if you want to regenerate it use these commands:

```
rails d controller welcome
rails g controller welcome
```

You can also generate this controller with method names by default.

For more information check out the [official guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html).

Comment: This duplicates the existing answer but with cell-phone talk. I will edit for grammar, but bear in mind that SO is kind of a *de facto* source for information and it should be presented as though we're adults.